# Approval Workflow Task Permissions

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I have a Modified OOTB Approval Workflow running on Custom List (modified in SPD). It creates a Task in the Tasks list. Now, I want to change the default permissions assigned to the Task Item. Right now it sets the Assigned To group Contribute permissions and the Created By field Read permissions.

I cannot find the step that edits the permissions and would like to just change that. I do not wanted the Created By user to have any permissions, and would like to assign the Assigned To group a custom permission level.

My best guess workaround is to create a new workflow that updates the permissions on the task item creation, but I would prefer something more elegant.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Designer has quiet powerful actions to change permissions on lists item like `Remove List Item Permissions` which allows you to specify which permission for which user you want to remove from which item), but they are only available if inside a `Impersonation Step`. If you want to use them inside a `Start Approval Process` action, then the `Start Approval Process` should be inside the  `Impersonation Step`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was getting at when I said make a new workflow. This is the solution that I ended up doing since I could not find where the permissions were set in the approval workflow. I just made it a list workflow that ran on task creation.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer 2010 does not have permission activities/actions OOB!

But, [Useful SharePoint Designer Custom Workflow Activities](http://spdactivities.codeplex.com/) give you some of the actions like:

- Grant Permission on Item - Allows granting of specified permission
  level on a specified item
- Delete List Item Permission Assignment - Allows deleting of specified
  permission level assignment for a given user
- Reset List Permissions Inheritance - removes any unique permissions
  assigned to an item by inheriting list permissions

You can install the wsp and leverage these activities!

I hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I should have mentioned I do have access to SharePoint Designer. We modified the Approval Workflow in SPD to send out emails and such. I am failing to find when it sets the unique permissions for the Task item thought.

Comment: The link given is for SharePoint Designer activities... Yes, they will add these activities to SharePoint Designer actions... Also you can try Jakobsen's answer!