# Approval Process

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

I'm trying to implement a simple approval process in SharePoint Designer. Everything is running smoothly except for one thing. People who weren't **assigned to** the tasks are able to approve/reject the task. I've looked at the **PermissionSet** and its value is **AssignedTo**. Same with **TaskProcessOwner** where I assigned it to the **Manager**.

Is there a setting that I am missing to disable the initiator of the work flow to be able to approve/reject a task?

Comment: Is this Visual Studio or SharePoint Designer workflow?

Comment: SharePoint Designer Workflow

Answer (score 1):

This looks previous stack exchange answer like a way to go:

[Approval Workflow Task Permissions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50335/approval-workflow-task-permissions)

For some step by step instructions see Nik's blog post:
http://nikpatel.net/2014/05/11/handy-sharepoint-designer-workflow-tip-configure-item-level-permissions/